# How to echo content into a series of new file generated by cat

Tags: cat, echo

I would like to write a loop to generate 22 R scripts with contents generated in echo. What went wrong in this loop that I could not get the 22 files with the corresponding content?

I tested `echo "i want that file" > file.r`

It works fine. Then I tested, it treated as two seperate process. First it echo the text, then it generated 22 empty files.

```
for i in `seq 1 22`; do
    echo "a <- read.delim('file${i}.txt', header=T, check.names=FALSE);
        library('splitstackshape');
        loc1 <- cSplit(a, 'V1', ':');
        rm(a);
        out <- cbind.data.frame(loc1$V1_1, loc1$V1_2);
        write.table(out, 'out_file${i}.txt', sep='\t', row.names=F, quote=F)"; 
> build_file${i}.r; done
```

Then I tried this.. still not working..

```
    for i in `seq 1 22`; do
    echo "a <- read.delim("file${i}.txt", header=T, check.names=FALSE);
    library("splitstackshape");
    loc1 <- cSplit(a, "V1", ":");
    rm(a);
    out <- cbind.data.frame(loc1$V1_1, loc1$V1_2);
    write.table(out, "out_file${i}.txt", sep="\t", row.names=F, quote=F)";
    cat > loc_chr${i}.r; done
```

Comment: Could someone also let me know why I got down vote for this question? Is it because I should not be asking how to use cat echo in a loop or did I violate any kind of rules on this site? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I completely follow the quoting in your script, and what you want the `cat` command to do, as it reads from the non-redirected stdin, i.e. presumably your keyboard. How about something like

```
for i in `seq 1 22`
  do cat <<- EOF > loc_chr${i}.r
"a <- read.delim("file${i}.txt", header=T, check.names=FALSE);
    library("splitstackshape");
    loc1 <- cSplit(a, "V1", ":");
    rm(a);
    out <- cbind.data.frame(loc1$V1_1, loc1$V1_2);
    write.table(out, "out_file${i}.txt", sep="\t", row.names=F, quote=F)"
EOF
   done
```

Comment: Thank you RudiC, I did not know the function "EOF"; I found this post that explained the usage. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/300129/how-do-i-use-cat-eof

Comment: Indeed, that `EOF` is not a command nor a function, but a deliberately chosen "word" / "delimiter", c.f. `man bash`, "Here Documents"

Answer (score 0):

Your first code sample isn't working because it has `> build_file${i}.r` on it's own line, which is redirecting nothing into 20 files. Append `> build_file${i}.r` to the end of your `echo`.

Your second code sample isn't working because of `cat` at the bottom. You don't supply what you want `cat` to concatenate, therefore it's waiting for input.

You should delete the `cat` line, and append `> loc_chr${i}.r` to the end of your `echo`.

```
for i in `seq 1 22`; do
echo "a <- read.delim("file${i}.txt", header=T, check.names=FALSE);
library("splitstackshape");
loc1 <- cSplit(a, "V1", ":");
rm(a);
out <- cbind.data.frame(loc1$V1_1, loc1$V1_2);
write.table(out, "out_file${i}.txt", sep="\t", row.names=F, quote=F)" > loc_chr${i}.r
done
```

Comment: Hi @Peschke, thanks for the suggestions. I tested a short script and came to the same conclusion, but as I just updated in the post, it did not generate the ideal results. Instead, there were 22 separate empty files while I see echo working at the terminal printing out all the text.

Comment: @Molly_K: I answered before your first edit. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you @Peschke, I learned that I had an extra ";" before I redirect the echo content to the output file. I will look into the reason why is that. Thank you for showing me how to work around the cat and echo function.